# Is there a better way to write using the Java 8 to populate the LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, java-8

I have some code that splits a String of letters, make a List with that and 
later, populate a LinkedHashMap of `Character` and `Integer` with the letter and its frequency.  The code is as following,

```
   List<String> values = Arrays.asList((subjects.split(",")));
            for (String value : values) {
                char v = value.charAt(0);
                map.put(v, map.containsKey(v) ? map.get(v) + 1 : 1);
            }
            map.put('X', 0);
```

How can I write it concisely with Java 8 ? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `Map.computeIfAbsent` which covers this case exactly.

Comment: Why are you splitting on comma? What does the input look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Character, Long> counts = Pattern.compile(",")
        .splitAsStream(subjects)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                s -> s.charAt(0),
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.counting()));
```

If you must have an `Integer` count, you can wrap the counting collector like this:

```
Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)
```

Another option (thanks [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126158/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-using-the-java-8-to-populate-the-linkedhashmap/42126377?noredirect=1#comment71434180_42126377)):

```
Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)
```

As a side note, you could replace your looping update with this:

```
map.merge(v, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: The question said it wants to count all characters, so I believe the regular expression and splitting is wrong.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh *The question said it wants to count all characters*. Really? Where?

Comment: ...populate a `LinkedHashMap` of `Character` and `Integer` with the letter and its frequency.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Where's the part about counting **all** the characters?

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but it doesn't say anything opposite.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh `subjects.split(",")` says a lot to me.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. But I believe it was another error.

Comment: This answer is correct and I accept it. I have a question: why can't I use LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> directly ? I use Long and this works fine, but, using the Integer will save the memory.

Comment: @Are you sure you read the answer? I specifically showed how to get `Integer`.

Comment: @Are: I doubt, that “using the Integer will save memory”. In your map, you have objects, not primitive data types. While these objects do encapsulate primitive values, they also are subject to JVM specific overhead and padding, equalizing the size differences between `Long` and `Integer`. As a fun fact, in the current version, `Collectors.summingLong(x -> 1L)` (and `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` respectively) is more efficient than `Collectors.counting()` for higher numbers of occurrences. But that will change in the next version.

Answer (score 3):

One liner:

```
Map<String, Long> frequency = Arrays.stream(input.split("(?<=.)\\W*"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

This counts all "word" characters (letters and digits).

Comment: It is recommended to use Function.identity() instead of s -> s as it will always return the same instance while each occurrence of s -> s will not only create its own instance but even have a distinct implementation class.

Comment: @Lalit Rao: that’s an implementation detail. Generally, a JRE is allowed to fold all occurrences of `whatever -> whatever` with the same target type into a single instance. Likewise, an implementation *may* return a different instance on each `Function.identity()` call. The actual recommendation is to use whatever you think it’s more readable.

Comment: @Lalit I did this because I thumbed in the code on my iphone and there's less characters to thumb, and actually I find `s -> s` easier to read

Comment: @Holger actually I find `s -> s` a lot easier to read than even just `identity()` (after `import  static ...Function.identity;`)

Comment: @Bohemian: that’s why I said “…use whatever *you* think it’s more readable”. Besides, I’d rarely use an `import static` for `Function.identity` as that would really reduce the clarity (like importing one of the gazillion `of` or `valueOf` or `create` factory methods whose meaning lies in the dark without the prepended type name).

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for something like:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Arrays.asList(subjects.split(""))
      .stream().map(s -> s.charAt(0))
      .forEach(c -> result.put(c, result.containsKey(c) ? result.get(c) + 1 : 1));
```

and a better solution is

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
subjects.chars().mapToObj(c->(char)c)
    .forEach(c -> result.put(c, result.containsKey(c) ? result.get(c) + 1 : 1));
```

Comment: Your second solution makes no sense.

Comment: @shmosel and what is the problem with it?

Comment: I assumed `split("")` was a typo. I see where you're coming from now, though I'm pretty sure you're mistaken.